# bootstrap horizontal alignment of form control groups

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have two form controls with labels. I want the labels to appear above the controls but the controls to appear next to each other. I can figure out how to do one or the other, but not both.

I currently have

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="select1">Select1</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <select id="select1">
            <option value="abc">ABC</option>
            <option value="def">DEF</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="text1">Text1</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <input id="text1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/BA4g7/

How can I make the two control groups horizontally aligned with each other? Do I need to put them in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This looks okay](http://jsfiddle.net/BA4g7/4/):

```
.control-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

However, if you want it to be *guaranteed* to stay on line (and not wrap down with narrow screen widths), then you need to wrap it in another `div` and set `white-space: nowrap` on that, [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BA4g7/5/).

Also, if you want it to look better, you will need to play with some dimensioning on the text input, [something like this looks good in my FF browser](http://jsfiddle.net/BA4g7/6/):

```
#text1 {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add a custom css class in your external css that are loaded after bootstrap, for overwrite native class that you might want to change. Personally I do this every time I use bootstrap.

So I create this class to fix the problem

```
.makeHorizontal{
  float:left;
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BA4g7/9/).